# Looking for guidance on how to write a script that will pull all users from 198 AD Groups, grouping the users to the group they are in. to report

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I have 198 groups in an OU in Active Directory that I need to get all members of those groups and then output the users grouped by the group they are in. Exp:

```
GP-1
  Tim
  Karen

GP-2
  Tom
  Harry
  Tim
```

A user can be in multiple groups.

```
$Groups = Get-AdGroup -SearchBase "OU=1,OU=2,OU=Groups,OU=3,DC=One,DC=Two" -Filter * | Select-Object -Property Name

## For Each loop to get members of each group
$Array = foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
## Define the search criteria for AD Search and capture in variable $Array
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group | Get-ADUser -Properties SamAccountName | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'SamAccountName'; Expression = {$_.SamAccountName}},
                  @{Name = 'GroupName'; Expression = {$Group}}

}
```

I was expecting to see each member/user in each group separated by group. Then, I was going to output that to a CSV file.

Comment: Do you want all members joined in 1 line? That would be terribly confusing if you export that to CSV later. You should expand a row per user having a group column as reference

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - that's what I am looking for, yes. Apologies if I was not clear.

Comment: Your code should do what you expected then, you just need to change `Expression = {$Group}}` to `Expression = {$Group.Name}}`

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to analyses like this, PsCustomObject is the medium of choice for me.
After putting all desired groups in you $Groups variable you could do something like this:

```
$Table = @()
foreach ($Group in $Groups){
    $GroupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group
    $Table += [pscustomobject] @{
        Group = $Group.Name
        Members = $GroupMembers.SamAccountName -join ','
    }
}
```

This will provide you a table with two columns.
The first column contains group names and the second column contains samaccountnames separated by a comma. You can then simply export it by

```
$Table | Export-CSV -Path $env:\TEMP\list.csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you for the code and assistance, I tried it but the output was as follows:

Group;"Members"
;"User1  User2"
;"User3"
;""
;"User4  User5SU"
;""

Comment: What I have now outputs like this:
Member    Group
user1    gp1
user2    gp1
user3    gp2
user4    gp3
user5    gp3
user6    gp3
user7    gp3

Which is ok but I would rather have the users listed under the group names.

Comment: It's tricky indeed. I've tried it for a while now because I am also interested in how I could accomplish that. Any further help is very welcome here.